# CollapsingToolbarLayout/Toolbar fades too early/late

Tags: android

My CollapsingToolbarLayout is not working accurate enough. Image 1 shows the initial state and image 2 the one, when I was scrolling down a little. The transition happens too early and it will end up in a (in this case) pink blank space. The same happens when scrolling up again.
Any way to fix that?

My layout:

```
<android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
    android:id="@+id/appbar"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="@dimen/activity_main_cover_height"
    android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar">

    <android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout
        android:id="@+id/collapsing_toolbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        app:contentScrim="?attr/colorPrimary"
        app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|exitUntilCollapsed">

      <RelativeLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content">

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/backdrop"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:scaleType="centerCrop"
                app:layout_collapseMode="parallax" />

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
                android:background="@color/transparent_background_dark"
                android:orientation="vertical"
                android:paddingLeft="@dimen/box_headline_padding"
                android:paddingStart="@dimen/box_headline_padding">

                <!-- ... -->

            </LinearLayout>

        </RelativeLayout>

        <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
            android:id="@+id/toolbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
            app:layout_collapseMode="pin"
            app:popupTheme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light" />

    </android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout>

</android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

<android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingBottom="0dp"
    app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior">

    <!-- ... -->
</android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView>
```

[image][image]

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Thanks to [when the morning](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5990846/when-the-morning-comes) comes I figured out the correct parameter `app:scrimVisibleHeightTrigger`
In the end I combined both

```
app:scrimAnimationDuration="300"
app:scrimVisibleHeightTrigger="60dp"
```

Answer (score 1):

Use this attribute in your CollapsingToolbarLayout:

```
        app:scrimAnimationDuration="600"
```

The time is in milliseconds.